# Try to prove the square of algebraic number is also an algebraic. Need some suggestion.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Try to prove the following:

If $a$ is an algebraic number then $a^2$ is also an algebraic number.

Use the quadratic formula for $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$
\begin{align*}
    x &= \frac{-b  \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \\
    x^2 &= \frac{b^2 + b^2 - 4ac \pm 2b\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{4a^2} \\
\end{align*} 
Since $\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}$ is an algebraic number, $x^2$ is also algebraic number.

Comment: For a given polynomial $p(x)$ with rational coefficients, the polynomial $p(-x)p(x)$ is even. Therefore, it can be written in the form $g(x^2)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$ with rational coefficients. If $p(a)=0$, then $g(a^2)=p(-a)p(a)=0$.

Comment: what you mean p(-x)p(x) is even?   if p(x) = x , then p(x) = x, p(-x) = -x => p(-x)p(x) = -x^2 => which is not an even polynomial?, sorry, LOL.. it is even..

Comment: Did you get it, or do you still have a question?

Comment: What I come up so far.   f(x)= x - a,  f(-x) = -x - a, f(x)(-x) = -x^2 + a^2 = 0 => g(x^2) = -x^2 + a^2 = 0?  => x^2 is algebraic number?

Comment: By the way, does my quadratic formula proof work?.. I did not see any problem so far. But it is not as elegant as your proof.

Comment: That would only prove, after adding some extra remarks, that an algebraic number that is the root of a quadratic polynomial has a square that is also algebraic.

Comment: Huh?  Is the $a$ in $ax^2 + bx + c$ the same $a$ as the algebraic number you were given and that you want to show that $a^2$ is algebraic? If so then $ax^2 + bx + c$ is not a polynomial with rational coefficients so you don'tknow that $x$ is algebraic and $x^2$ being algebraic is not what you are trying to show.

Comment: Sorry, i mean the x is the root of polynomial, not the a in the quadratic formula. yep, I use the wrong letter for the root of polynomial,

Comment: we did not know whether $\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} is algebraic number or not, I think my proof has problem

Answer (score 1):

Since our OP 1234 hasn't specified the field over which $\alpha$ is supposed to be algebraic, I presume he means "an algebraic number over the rationals $\Bbb Q$".

Since $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$,

$[\Bbb Q(\alpha): \Bbb Q] < \infty; \tag 1$

we observe that

$\alpha \in \Bbb Q(\alpha) \Longrightarrow \alpha^2 \in \Bbb Q(\alpha) \Longrightarrow \Bbb Q(\alpha^2) \subset \Bbb Q(\alpha); \tag 2$

then in light of (1) we have

$[\Bbb Q(\alpha^2): \Bbb Q] \le [\Bbb Q(\alpha): \Bbb Q] < \infty, \tag 3$

which shows that $\alpha^2$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$.

The situation submits to considerable generalization:  let $F$ be any field, $E/F$ any extension of $F$, and $\alpha \in E$ algebraic over $F$; then as in (1) and (2),

$[F(\alpha):F] < \infty, \tag 4$

$\alpha \in F(\alpha) \Longrightarrow \alpha^2 \in F(\alpha) \Longrightarrow F(\alpha^2) \subset F(\alpha), \tag 5$

from which as in (3)

$[F(\alpha^2):F] \le [F(\alpha):F] < \infty; \tag 6$

thus $\alpha^2$ is algebraic over $F$.